# using linq to filter data from a dataset - MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am literally a fetus when it comes to MVC-4-- this is my first week trying to use it.So please forgive me ignorance.
I have created a dataset   and I managed to display the data as  `Tables[0]` 
What I have been asked to do  now is to filter the `Tables[0]` using linq and a parameter .. I  have been looking at some other code and looks something like this..

```
public void Execute()
{
    _model._contractsModel.UserAccess = new UserAccessQuery().GetData();

    IEnumerable<string> userAccess = (from row in _model._contractsModel.UserAccess.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                                      where row.Field<string>("NOTES") == _model.filteredName
                                      select row);

    var list = new List<string>();
    if (userAccess.Count() != 0)
    {
        list = userAccess.ToList();
        _model.UserAccess = list[0];
    }
}
```

However the 'where' is telling me that it is wrong

Comment: Surely you could simply use `row.NOTES == _model.filteredName`.  If you can't, there's your problem...the property doesn't exist on the record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your LINQ expression, yo are doing `select row`. That means, after your where clause filteration gets executed, it is going to select a collection of `DataRow` ,specifically  `EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow>`. But you are trying to assign that to a `List<string>`. That is the problem.

You should either change the variable type from List to `EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow>` or you may even use [type inference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384061.aspx)

```
EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow> userAccess = (from row in 
                                  _model._contractsModel.UserAccess.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                                  where row.Field<string>("NOTES") == _model.filteredName
                                  select row);
```

**Or**

```
var userAccess = (from row in 
                                  _model._contractsModel.UserAccess.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                                  where row.Field<string>("NOTES") == _model.filteredName
                                  select row);
```

In both the cases, userAccess type will be same. So if you want a single column value, you may access it like

```
if (userAccess.Any())
{
    var firstNoteRow = userAccess.First();
    var notStringVal = firstNoteRow["NOTES"];
}
```

**Or** if you want do the the column selection in your LINQ expression itself, you can do that as well.

```
var userAccessNotes = (from row in 
                                  _model._contractsModel.UserAccess.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                                  where row.Field<string>("NOTES") == _model.filteredName
                                  select row["NOTES"] as string).ToList();
```

Here `userAccessNotes` will be of type `List<string>`